# What is the difference between payload and meta of redux toolkit action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, action, redux-toolkit

Hello I am currently studying redux-toolkit. As the title, I'm curious about the difference between the two. I would appreciate it if you could let me know in which case result data goes into the payload and in which case it goes into the meta.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fykjq.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNoG7.png)

```js
const templateGetOne = createAsyncThunk('template/check/code', async (code) => {
  const response = axios.get(`${api}/temp/info?template_code=${code}`)
  const data = await response.data
  console.log('response data>>>>', data)
  return data
})
```

```js
    builder.addCase(templateGetOne.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.code = action.meta
      console.log('state code: ', state.code)
      console.log('action: ', action)
      console.log('action payload: ', action.payload)
      console.log('action meta: ', action.meta)
    })
```

```js
  const handleCheck = (event) => {
    dispatch(templateGetOne(event.target.value))
  }
```

I'm guessing that maybe something went wrong in the process of passing the action and finding the reducer. However, I don't know the exact difference between the two and it's hard to figure out because I still don't understand the principle of how it works. Help

Comment: Ah, the value I sent goes into the meta. The problem seems to be that the action is not working properly. I'll look for more reasons.